# Hiding the Console Window When Running Process as a User with DllImports

Tags: c#, winapi, cmd, console

**Update**

Error message with below attempt:

**I am seeing this error output from TEST.EXE (retrieved with 2> in CMD line):**

```
ERROR: Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.
```

**But not seeing any error from the process which is calling the EXE**

Tried, as per the below suggestions (I think) to create a process which calls the process which I need:

```
    public static void getProc()
    {
        SecureString ss = CreatePW();

        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "\"/C cd C:\\users\\user.name\\desktop & TEST\"")
        {
            WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            CreateNoWindow = true,

            WorkingDirectory = @"C:\windows\system32",
            Verb = "runas",
            Domain = "DOMAIN",
            UserName = "zzkillcitrix",
            Password = ss
        };

        string asd = "";
        Process proc = Process.Start(startInfo);

        proc.OutputDataReceived += (x, y) => asd += y.Data;
        proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
        proc.WaitForExit();
    }
```

Where TEST.EXE is a build of the following(sends the argument to CMD):

```
    public static void getProc()
    {
        SecureString ss = CreatePW();

        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "Command_which_requires_user_authentication_goes_here")
        {
            WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
        };

        Process proc = Process.Start(startInfo);

        proc.OutputDataReceived += (x, y) => asd += y.Data;
        proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
        proc.WaitForExit();
    }
```

When running TEST.exe by double clicking, I am still seeing the CMD window.
When running the above (top method), TEST.exe doesn't appear to be running, as I am not seeing the messagebox windows.

This is probably because the user credentials are not being passed to the EXE file.

---

I have a process which I call using the following ProcessStartInfo details:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/C tasklist /S " + server + " /FI \"SESSION eq " + sessID + "\" /FO CSV /NH")
{
    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    RedirectStandardError = true,
    CreateNoWindow = true,

    WorkingDirectory = @"C:\windows\system32",
    Verb = "runas",
    Domain = "DOMAIN",
    UserName = "zzkillcitrix",
    Password = ss,
}
```

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.createnowindow.aspx) I know that when running a Process such as this as a user, the CreateNoWindow and WindowStyle properties do not work. This includes setting WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden.

I am therefore trying to achieve a Console-less Process.Start by declaring the following:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

const int SW_HIDE = 0;
const int SW_SHOW = 5;
```

And then calling proc like so:

```
Process proc = Process.Start(startInfo);

var handle = proc.MainWindowHandle;
ShowWindow(handle, SW_HIDE);

proc.OutputDataReceived += (x, y) => procList.Add(y.Data);
proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
proc.WaitForExit();
```

When the process runs, a console window still flashes up briefly. Am I trying to hide a Window Handle where this isn't being recognised as a Console Window?

I have also tried calling the ShowWindow method, generally, at the beginning of the Program, but the console window still appears.

Would appreciate any guidance on this at all.

Comment: Every problem can be solved with an extra level of indirection.  Create a small non-console project (Output type = Windows Application) and run that one instead.  It can start the console mode app.

Comment: Hi Hans, thanks for your suggestion. My application already outputs to type Windows Application - Would running a second one from this one make a difference? It also seems wrong that I need to create 2 applications for this, doesn't that mean I will end up with 2 EXE files once it is built? Thanks again

Comment: Well sure, you can use your own app as well, as long as you run it with that other user account.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I don't understand why the WindowStyle commands don't just work, it seems stupid that I can log in as any admin user I want via process.Start, but I have no control over the console window's appearance  ... I will look into your suggestion but I don't think having 2 different apps is an acceptable solution in my case

Comment: If 2 EXE files is an inacceptable limitation, you can always package one of those EXE's as a binary resource into the other EXE. This is doable, but needlessly adds complexity. Right now you have precisely **one** option that exposes the desired behavior. I'm sure it'll become an acceptable solution in due time.

Comment: Tried to call an EXE containing my process from my Program, but it doesn't seem to detect the user credentials! I've posted the code above, but I am probably grossly misunderstanding something here ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way of doing this I could find that actually worked is by running the commands via a remote PowerShell session as a user who has full domain access:

```
static class Ps
{
    private const string RemoteHost = "ADMINSERVER.DOMAIN1.co.uk";
    private static string _errors;

    /// <summary>
    /// Executes the given command over a remote powershell session
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="args"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static Collection<PSObject> RemoteCommand(string args)
    {
        SupportMi.Trace = $"Remote Command({args}) {{";

        var script = BuildScript(args);
        var results = Execute(script);

        SupportMi.Trace = $"RES: {results[0]} ERR: {_errors} }}";
        return results;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Takes a complete script and executes it over a powershell Runspace. In this case it is being
    /// sent to the server, and the results of the execution are checked for any errors. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="script"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static Collection<PSObject> Execute(string script)
    {
        var results = new Collection<PSObject>();

        // Using a runspace
        using (var runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace())
        {
            runspace.Open();

            using (var pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline())
            {
                pipeline.Commands.AddScript(script);

                try
                {
                    results = pipeline.Invoke();
                    var errors = pipeline.Error.Read(pipeline.Error.Count);
                    foreach (var error in errors)
                    {
                        _errors += error;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    results.Add(new PSObject(ex.Message));
                    SupportMi.Trace = ex.Message;
                }
            }
        }

        return results;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Takes a string argument to be sent to the remote powershell session and arranges it in the correct format,
    /// ready to be sent to the server.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="args"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static string BuildScript(string args)
    {
        // Build the script
        var script = Creds() + Environment.NewLine +
                    $"Invoke-Command -session $sessions -ScriptBlock {{ {args} /U DOMAIN1\\adminusername /P adminpassword }}" + Environment.NewLine +
                    "Remove-PSSession -Session $sessions" + Environment.NewLine +
                    "exit";

        return script;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the credentials for a remote PowerShell session in the form 
    /// of a few lines of PowerShell script. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static string Creds()
    {
        return "$pw = convertto-securestring -AsPlainText -Force -String \"adminpassword\"" + Environment.NewLine +
               "$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist \"DOMAIN1\\adminusername\",$pw" + Environment.NewLine +
               $"$sessions = New-PSSession -ComputerName {RemoteHost} -credential $cred";
    }
}
```

So to maintain a console-less action we can call the `RemoteCommand` method and pass in the command we want to send. `RemoteCommand` will first build our query/command using `BuildScript` and `Creds` (for the admin credentials).

This is then sent to the `Execute` method, which creates a new PowerShell `RunSpace`, which can run the command.

Some caveats of using this method :

- The app must be run on the domain on which the "admin" server exists
- There must exist an admin account which has access to any machine which wishes to run this code as well as the server (in this case, `ADMINSERVER`)
- Any errors will exist on the remote server, so we must take care to handle these properly so that they are passed back into our application

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized
```

To

```
WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
```

Comment: Hi EyIM, This also doesn't hide the CMD window. The ProcessWindowStyle seems to stop working when running the command as a different user

Comment: Looks like it is not working if creating the process as a different user. Another approach I can think of is to create a wrapper non-console application that creates the cmd process. This application will not be console by default so wont show the window.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. My project is a Windows Form Application - would this still be classed as a console app in the sense that the cmd window will automatically be generated when sending to CMD?

Comment: No, unless you create the window.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't seem to work, but I suspect I have probably done something wrong! I created an EXE which calls my CMD line, and then called that from within a C# program which did have the credentials, but they don't seem to pipe through to the EXE

Comment: I am seeing this error output from TEST.EXE (retrieved with 2> in CMD line):

ERROR: Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.

But not seeing any error from the process which is calling the EXE